# Speedview sólo muestra el último elemento recibido de una BBDD (ROOM)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-room

Tengo en una BBDD 10 velocidades almacenadas, las cuales las quiero mostrar en un speedview, pero al ejecutar la app sólo se muestra la última velocidad. He probado de poner un Handler para que en cada repetición del bucle tarde unos segundos en ejecutarse y así poder mostrar cada velocidad, pero el resultado siempre es el mismo (sólo se muestra la última velocidad).

```
private fun cambiarVelocidad() {

var speedometer = findViewById<SpeedView>(R.id.speedView)
var querys = db.vehiculoDao()
var todasVelocidades = querys.getTodasVelocidades()
var contador = 1
for (i in todasVelocidades){
    var velocidadActual = querys.getVelocidadById(contador)
    speedometer.speedTo(velocidadActual.toFloat())
    
    if(velocidadActual != null){
        contador++
        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(
            {
                speedometer.speedTo(velocidadActual.toFloat())
                cambiarCuentarrevoluciones(speedometer.speed.toInt())

            },
            3000 // value in milliseconds
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tendrías que debuggar un poco, mi consejo es que empiezes con la query getTodasVelocidades() y comprobar que efectivamente te esta devolviendo todas las velocidades y no únicamente la última.
podrias hacer una impresión del contador, a ver cuantas veces entra en el bucle, etc.

Comment: Esto ya lo he ido comprobando y todo se supone que funciona bien (existen todas las velocidades, el contador también funciona, ...) pero siempre devuelve sólo el último. Estoy muy perdido con esto, no entiendo qué falla.